# Hibernate AliasToBean Transformer, CHAR(1) to String: "expected type = java.lang.String" Error

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am working on an application where an AliasToBean Transformer is used to populate a POJO bean. The DB is Oracle.

```
String sql = "select app.id as \"applicationId\", 
              app.valid_flag as \"validFlag\" from applications_t app";
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Report.class));     
    // run the query
    List<Report> result = (List<Report>)query.list();
```

One field is a String which gets its value from a `CHAR(1 CHAR)`.

```
public class Report implements Serializable {
    String validFlag;  // With Getter/Setter
    //...
}
```

I get an error for CHAR-to-String conversion as follows:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertySetterAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred 
while calling setter for property [validFlag (expected type = java.lang.String)]; 
target = [com.app.Report@1a89016a], property value = [N] setter of com.app.Report.validFlag
    at ...
```

A `CHAR(1)` property value of `N` could not be auto-stored in a String. What's the solution?

Note that this isn't a Table bean where I can do `@Column(columnDefinition="CHAR")`. This is a custom POJO after transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cast(app.valid_flag as VARCHAR2(1)) as \"validFlag\"` in your query. Or `query.addScalar("validFlag", StringType.INSTANCE).list()`.